# Installing Magento using SSH to bypass web based installer

Tags: magento, ssh

I know that I am supposed to use (;) to separate multiple commands but what is the correct format for issuing all these commands in a **single line** to install magento using ssh to bypass the web based installer?

```
php-cli -f install.php -- \
--license_agreement_accepted "yes" \
--locale "en_US" \
--timezone "America/Los_Angeles" \
--default_currency "USD" \
--db_host "DB_HOST" \
--db_name "DB_NAME" \
--db_user "DB_USER" \
--db_pass "DB_PASS" \
--url "SITE_URL" \
--use_rewrites "yes" \
--use_secure "no" \
--secure_base_url "" \
--use_secure_admin "no" \
--admin_firstname "FIRST_NAME" \
--admin_lastname "LAST_NAME" \
--admin_email "EMAIL_ADDRESS" \
--admin_username "USERNAME" \
--admin_password "PASSWORD"
```

Comment: Does it not work? What error do you get?

Comment: I have edited the question to more accurately ask what I was wanting to know what is the correct format for putting all the commands in a single line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those don't seem to be commands but parameters. Putting them all into a single line:

```
php-cli -f install.php --license_agreement_accepted "yes" --locale "en_US"  ...
```

should work.

Comment: so I do keep (--) but remove the (/)